# How to make a bibliography without the header using Biber and the Friggeri CV template?

Tags: biblatex, biber, friggeri-cv

I want to make a cv using the Friggeri template I found there :
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv

But since I only have articles in the publication section I do not want the subsection heading to appear. I find how to change it to what ever I want but I do not know how to make it disappear totally. Does someone know how to do it ?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square 

bracket to remove colors from this template for printing

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\begin{document}

\header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst} % Your name and current job title/field
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PUBLICATIONS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{publications}

\printbibsection{article}{I don't want this line to appear} % Print all articles from the bibliography

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Here the result I get from the code:
[image]

I already try to the following:

```
\printbibsection{article}{}
```

But then it automaticaly write "Bibliography"

And also :

```
\printbibsection[header=none]{article}
```

But it does not work at all.

Note to use the template: In order to compile the file, you have either to have the "new helvetica" font or to change it in the class file found under the given link.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you want `\renewcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=none]
  \end{refsection}
}`? Alternatively, to preserve spacing, try `\printbibsection{article}{~}`.

Comment: A simple `\printbibsection{article}` won't work because the mandatory second argument is missing, LaTeX will try to get it and all hell might break loose, or the argument is simply a normal space or empty as in `\printbibsection{article}{}` which one could expect to work, but `biblatex` is clever and ignores an empty argument (and even one that is only a space) as an input error. You will have to use a tie `~`, or the proper solution from above.

Comment: thanks @moewe for the help, where do I have to put the line from your first comment ? In the préambule of the document or directly under the publication section ?

Comment: The preamble would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nicest solution is probably

```
\renewcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{%
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=none]
  \end{refsection}}
```

Just put this into your preamble.

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} 
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\renewcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{%
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=none]
  \end{refsection}}

\begin{document}
\header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst} 
\section{publications}

\printbibsection{article}{foooo} 
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

Alternatively, without the above redefinition you can only say

```
\printbibsection{article}{~}
```

then the spacing will be as if there was an empty headline.

Comment: Thank you for the help @moewe. It work fine. The Alternative is something I allready found out but then the spacing is not correct with the other section...

Comment: @PierrickBersier Precisely, it depends a bit on what you want.